# Using the Batch API with AJAX?

Tags: ajax

I have been trying to figure out how to use the Batch API in an overlay via AJAX, but are not sure that's possible at all? - As far as I can see the batch API, when javascript is enabled, calls the misc/batch.js, which at status=100 performs a window.location to return to the page who requested the batch.

To my knowledge, it's not possible to catch and prevent this event (Without showing the user a popup with the choice of staying on or leaving the page). - So right now I don't see a way to achieve this without running batch as if, javascript was not turned on?

Am I missing some Drupal magic here?

Comment: Don't think it's a duplicate, although the "solution" might be the same.. But initially I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require me to override core files in Drupal (In this case the misc/batch.js file)

Comment: But there is a working solution for your problem.

Comment: The only solution i can see in the thread you linked to is to unset the the "misc/batch.js" and instead implement your own script... This just sound a bit hackish to me.. From all i have learned that's not the way to do stuff in Drupal.. But i might miss something here?

Comment: Yes i agree with that. `Dont hack Core` is drupal policy. but i cant find any quick solution for this.

Comment: Not necessarily looking for a quick solution.. But is finding it hard to see any solution for this...

Comment: EDIT: Not thinking strait :)

Comment: Well, now i have tried to look trough the Batch API, the batch.inc file and batch.js file, and from what i can see this simply doesen't appear to be possible to achieve without hacking Drupal core one way or the other

- I don't see any relevant hooks in the batch API, and no way to catch and alter the window.location event.

Comment: You _could_ monkey patch the JS, as is always possible, and then you would not need to hack core. Ugly, but certainly do-able.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible without hacking core. It needs a bit of fiddling, but you can basically just use `Drupal.ProgressBar` for an existing batch process, providing your own `updateCallback` to control its behaviour.

I have successfully done this in every version of Drupal since Drupal 7, but can't share my code here unfortunately.

One example I found for Drupal 8 explains the gist of it, although it's not explicitly covering the modal part of the question: https://www.hashbangcode.com/article/drupal-8-running-batch-through-ajax-request

I'll share a slightly modified (and untested) version of the code example from the linked article:

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  'use strict';

  Drupal.behaviors.account = {
    attach: function attach(context, settings) {
      var progressBar = void 0;

      function updateCallback(progress, status, pb) {
        $('#updateprogress').html(progress + '%');
        if (progress === '100') {
          pb.stopMonitoring();
          // And do whatever suits your needs, redirecting or updating some DOM
          // elements
        }
      }

      function errorCallback(pb) {
      }

      $.ajax({
        url: Drupal.url('account/loading/ajax'),
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function success(value) {
          progressBar = new Drupal.ProgressBar('updateprogress', updateCallback, 'POST', errorCallback);
          progressBar.startMonitoring(BATCH_URL + '&op=do', 10);
        }
      });
    }
  };
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

`BATCH_URL` is the url that you get after setting up the batch process in PHP. I would also end the process with a `BATCH_URL + '&op=finished'` to do cleanup on the server, evaluate the process or whatever makes sense in the specific context.

You can also extend the `Drupal.ProgressBar.prototype` object to further modify the behaviour of it and adapt it your needs, e.g. by overriding its `setProgress` to do more fine grained updates or provide server side generated messages.

Answer (score 0):

****Steps To Run batch through jquery ajax request:****

**1. Create controller in which batch API code ‘ll be added**

**Snippet code:**

```
public function updateNodeData(Request $request, $nojs = 'nojs') {
    $method = $request->server->get('REQUEST_METHOD');
    $ajaxResponse = new AjaxResponse();
    // Add logic to check whether request to batch controller by
    // post method or not so that batch process not redirect to batch
    // window itself (i.e. by default core functionality)
    if ($nojs == 'ajax' && $method == 'POST') {
      $all_values = $request->request->all();
      $fields = $all_values['fields'];

      $node_storage = $this->entityTypeManager()->getStorage('node');
      $query = $node_storage->getQuery();

      $ids = $query->condition('type', $fields['content_type'])
        ->accessCheck(FALSE)
        ->execute();

      $batch_builder = new BatchBuilder();
      $batch_builder
        ->setTitle($this->t('Updating Data ..'))
        ->setFinishCallback([
          '\Drupal\batch_example_without_redirect\NodeData',
          'exportFinished',
        ])
        ->setInitMessage($this->t('Updating Node.'))
        ->setErrorMessage($this->t('The process has encountered an error.'));

      $ids_chunk = array_chunk($ids, 100);
      foreach ($ids_chunk as $id) {
        $batch_builder->addOperation([
          '\Drupal\batch_example_without_redirect\NodeData',
          'processNodeData',
        ],
        [
          $id,
        ]);
      }

      batch_set($batch_builder->toArray());

      // Get batch.
      $batch =& batch_get();

      $batch['progressive'] = TRUE;

      // Create the batch_process() to initiate batch process.
      $response = batch_process();

      $batch_id = $batch['id'] ?? '0';

      // Return the response to the ajax output.
      return $ajaxResponse->addCommand(new BaseCommand($batch_id, $response->getTargetUrl()));

    }

    return $ajaxResponse;

}
```

**2. Then call the controller/endpoint through jquery ajax request in which batch API code added so that batch process ‘ll be initiate**

**Snippet code:**

```
  // Call batch controller by ajax & post method.
        const url = 'update-node-data/ajax';
        $.ajax({
          url: Drupal.url(url),
          type: 'POST',
          data: {
            'fields': settings.user_submit_val.fields,
          },
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function success(value) {
            batch_id = value[0].command;
            // Display batch progress
            progressBar = new Drupal.ProgressBar('updateprogress', updateCallback, 'POST');
            progressBar.setProgress(0, 'Updating Data');
            progressBar.startMonitoring(value[0].data + '&op=do', 10);
          }
        });
```

**3. After batch completed its execution** :

Add check if progress == 100 that mean if all the items in batch processed, then call the batch finished callback endpoint through the jquery ajax request

**Snippet code:**

```
function updateCallback(progress, status, pb) {
    $('#updateprogress').html(progress + '%');
      if (progress === '100') {
        pb.stopMonitoring();
        // Call the finishCallback()
        $.ajax({
          url: Drupal.url('batch?id=' + batch_id + '&op=finished'),
          type: 'POST',
          contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function success(val) {
            window.location.reload();
          }
        });
      }
  }
```

**Note:** if you ‘ll skip above mentioned step 3 : then code added in batch finished callback ‘ll never execute.

**If you want to pass some dynamic user selected values to batch then you need to add some additional steps along with above mentioned steps:**

1. Create custom form & on submit form, call the ajax callback which ‘ll send user submit data from form to jquery.
2. Then in the attached jquery file get the user submit form values & pass these values to the batch controller by jquery ajax request.
3. Fetch the user submit form values in batch controller & use it as per logic.

**Note: For complete example you can download demo module from [here](https://github.com/poojasharma48/batch_example_without_redirect) to see working example of it for the reference.**